# A site where human bones have been discovered

Tags: expressions, phrase-requests, synonyms, terminology

Is there a shorter way of saying "other sites where human bones have been discovered"? I mean a site that is not a burial site, e.g a person has an heart attack, falls down on the ground and dies but nobody finds the body (and therefore it is not buried) and it just decomposes and a couple of hundred years later somebody finds his remains.

English is not my native language.

Comment: If it's just happenstance that bones are found somewhere, then that place really isn't a bone site.  Or am I missing the point of your question?

Comment: Hi @Mari-Anne L. can you please provide more information to show how you intend using the phrase. What comes before 'other sites...'? Thanks:)

Comment: Are you looking for an archeological term?

Answer (score 1):

There are words like burial place, bone yard and bone orchard.

But for the example that you have given, **final resting place** fits the description.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's just a site where **human remains** (or just **[remains](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/remains)** for short) have been found.

Another term for a place where human bones are deliberately kept is **[ossuary](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ossuary)**, but that does not fit your example.